# What is the correct syntax to write "merge statement" in PostgreSQL 9.6.2

Tags: postgresql, merge

code :It is merge query which is running on Postgres 9.6.2 and giving syntax error.

```
<<!--It is giving syntax error--->
MERGE INTO timesheets.timesheet_report AS tgt USING timesheets.tmp_timesheet_report AS src ON src.FMNo = tgt.FMNo
    AND src.ts_start_dt = tgt.ts_start_dt
    AND src.charge_code = tgt.charge_code WHEN NOT MATCHED
    INSERT (tgt.FIRST_NAME,
            tgt.LAST_NAME)
    VALUES(src.FIRST_NAME,
           src.LAST_NAME) WHEN MATCHED
    UPDATE
    SET tgt.FIRST_NAME = src.FIRST_NAME,
        tgt.LAST_NAME = src.LAST_NAME;
```

Comment: Merge statements vary by provider, pasting code from one RDMS to another does not mean it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO table_name [your usual insert syntax here]
ON CONFLICT [some conflict definition]
DO UPDATE SET column1 = EXCLUDED.value1
```

So I guess your query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO timesheets.timesheet_report (FMNo, ts_start_dt, charge_code, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
SELECT src.FMNo, src.ts_start_dt, src.charge_code, src.FIRST_NAME, src.LAST_NAME FROM timesheets.tmp_timesheet_report AS src
ON CONFLICT (FMNo, ts_start_dt, charge_code)
DO UPDATE
SET FIRST_NAME = EXCLUDED.FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME = EXCLUDED.LAST_NAME;
```

If you don't have primary key or unique index, then you need to `create unique index on timesheets.timesheet_report using btree (FMNo, ts_start_dt, charge_code);`

Comment: You are right, I've corrected code. Now it says only that I'm missing tables, so should be OK.